# List.Contains Suspicious Call

Tags: java, list

I am attempting to run a while loop based on if a char array contains a given char.  I thought I could accomplish this with the following:

```
while(Arrays.asList(letterMatrix).contains(keyword.charAt(i-1)))
```

Where letterMatrix is a char [][] and keyword is a String.

But I get the following warning in NetBeans: Suspicious call to java.util.Collection.contains: Given object cannot contain instances of char (expected char[]).

I'm a java novice, but I interpret this to mean that .contains is expecting an array, and I don't see why that would be.

What am I missing?

Comment: We need to see the underlying implementation of your code.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(char[][])` will return `List<char[]>`, figure out now :)

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList(letterMatrix)` will produce this object `List<Char[]>`, if you look at the method `contains()` it expects the object you are looking for to match the type of the list, so you are looking for a `char` in a list of arrays of `char`.

**EDIT**: see comments

```
List<Character> checkList = new ArrayList<Character>();
for(char[] charArray : letterMatrix) {
    for(char aChar : charArray) {
        checkList.add(aChar);
    }
}
while(checkList.contains(keyword.charAt(i-1)));
```

Comment: This makes sense, I thought the .asList method took the elements of a array and put them into a list, hence a List<char>.  Is there a way to accomplish my original intent of creating a list of chars to search through?

Comment: asList takes an array and makes a list of objects in that array. If that array contains another array it will create a list of arrays. I will add an implementation of what u want to do, it is not optimal but it should get u started.

Comment: Note that `letterMatrix` is of type `char[][]`, not `Character[][]`. Therefore, `Arrays.asList(chars)` will return a list containing the single element `chars` (not a `List<char>`, as no such type exists in Java. (Java only support reference types as type parameters).

Comment: I forget there is no autoboxing for arrays in java, silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you probably don't want to call `Arrays.asList(...)` in your while loop declaration; this method returns a new ArrayList on each invocation. Also, as the other answers suggest, the returned value will be a `List<char[]>`. So, try:

```
public void testTwoDimAsList() {
    char[][] arr = new char[][]{{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'1', '2', '3'}};
    List<char[]> asList = Arrays.asList(arr);
    // ...
}
```

Of course, the running time of `#contains` in an array list is linear, and that may not be optimal either.

Comment: That won't look for the character 'a' in the array it will look for an array containing 'a' in the list.

Comment: Oops, true enough. I'll just remove that part ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about. `Arrays.deepToString(letterMatrix).contains("" + keyword.charAt(i-1));`

For your case this is the fastest method. It turns your matrix into a String and then searches your char in it.

Comment: Thank you this accomplished just what I wanted!  I don't know enough to comment on it's efficiency, but I think for my purposes it will do wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmin and Tnem have already pointed out why that warning is justified, as it indeed indicates a bug. Here's how to fix it:

```
boolean contains(char[][] matrix, char wanted) {
    for (char[] line : matrix) {
        for (char c : line) {
            if (c == wanted) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

while (contains(letterMatrix, keyword.charAt(i-1)) {
    ....
}
```

Of course, as the two nested loop hint at, this solution will be somewhat slow if the matrix is big. A data structure supporting efficient lookups might be called for.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so basically what you need to understand is `char[]` cannot be compared to the PDT `char`.

You must iterate through the newly made list and create new lists on top of that.

e.g.

`while(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(letterMatrix).get(x)).contains(keyword.charAt(i-1)))`